# Spring data elasticsearch unable to connect to elasticsearch instance

Tags: java, spring, maven, elasticsearch, spring-data

How to understand a [spring-doc](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/elasticsearch/docs/current/reference/html/)? The [example](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-examples/tree/master/elasticsearch/example) provided doesn't work.

I am unable to bind together the pieces to form a basic example of saving and querying elasticsearch using Spring-Data-Elastic search. Can someone, point to some resource which actually works?

All classes are in the package `elasticsearch`. Anyhow here is my code:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    @Autowired
    private MovieRepository repository;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {

        // save a couple of movies
        repository.save(new Movie("tt1979320", "Rush", 2013, Arrays.asList("Action", "Biography", "Drama")));
        repository.save(new Movie("tt0111161", "The Shawshank Redemption", 1994, Arrays.asList("Crime", "Drama")));


    }
}
```

Pojo

```
@Document(indexName = "moviedb", type = "movie")
public class Movie {

    @Id
    private String id;

    private String name;

    private Integer year;

    private List<String> genre;

    public Movie() {
    }

    public Movie(String id, String name, Integer year, List<String> genre) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.year = year;
        this.genre = genre;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Integer getYear() {
        return year;
    }

    public void setYear(Integer year) {
        this.year = year;
    }

    public List<String> getGenre() {
        return genre;
    }

    public void setGenre(List<String> genre) {
        this.genre = genre;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Movie [id=" + id + ", name=" + name + ", year=" + year + ", genre=" + genre + "]";
    }

}
```

Spring Data repo for ElasticSearch

```
@Repository
public interface MovieRepository extends ElasticsearchRepository<Movie, String>{

    List<Movie> findByName(String name);
    List<Movie> findByYear(Integer year);
    List<Movie> findByGenre(List<String> genre);

}
```

Service class

```
@Service
public class MovieService{

    @Autowired
    private MovieRepository repository;

    public List<Movie> findByName(String name) {
        return repository.findByName(name);
    }

    public List<Movie> findByYear(Integer year) {
        return repository.findByYear(year);
    }

    public List<Movie> findByGenre(List<String> genre) {
        return repository.findByGenre(genre);
    }

}
```

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>elasticsearch</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-data-guide</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>gs-accessing-data-elasticsearch</name>
    <description>Spring Data for Elasticsearch guide</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.1.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

Some examples have created an Elasticsearch template with this. I haven't quite understood why is the Elasticsearch template required and how to create one.

I used elasticsearch 1.7 with this and received the following error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.netty.MessageChannelHandler.handleException(MessageChannelHandler.java:179) ~[elasticsearch-2.4.4.jar:2.4.4]
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.netty.MessageChannelHandler.handlerResponseError(MessageChannelHandler.java:174) ~[elasticsearch-2.4.4.jar:2.4.4]
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.netty.MessageChannelHandler.messageReceived(MessageChannelHandler.java:122) ~[elasticsearch-2.4.4.jar:2.4.4]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.java:70) [netty-3.10.6.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564) [netty-3.10.6.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$DefaultChannelHandlerContext.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:791) [netty-3.10.6.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:296) [netty-3.10.6.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.frame.FrameDecoder.unfoldAndFireMessageReceived(FrameDecoder.java:462) [netty-3.10.6.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.frame.FrameDecoder.callDecode(FrameDecoder.java:443) [netty-3.10.6.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.frame.FrameDecoder.messageReceived(FrameDecoder.java:303) [netty-3.10.6.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.java:70) [netty-3.10.6.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564) [netty-3.10.6.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:559) [netty-3.10.6.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:268) [netty-3.10.6.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:255) [netty-3.10.6.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.read(NioWorker.java:88) [netty-3.10.6.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.process(AbstractNioWorker.java:108) [netty-3.10.6.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioSelector.run(AbstractNioSelector.java:337) [netty-3.10.6.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.run(AbstractNioWorker.java:89) [netty-3.10.6.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.run(NioWorker.java:178) [netty-3.10.6.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.util.ThreadRenamingRunnable.run(ThreadRenamingRunnable.java:108) [netty-3.10.6.Final.jar:na]
    at org.jboss.netty.util.internal.DeadLockProofWorker$1.run(DeadLockProofWorker.java:42) [netty-3.10.6.Final.jar:na]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_112]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_112]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_112]
```

Running with elasticsearch 2.3, I am getting the following error:

```
2017-02-17 17:52:00.147  WARN 16795 --- [           main] org.elasticsearch.client.transport       : [Astron] node {#transport#-1}{127.0.0.1}{127.0.0.1:9300} not part of the cluster Cluster [elasticsearch], ignoring...
2017-02-17 17:52:00.415 ERROR 16795 --- [           main] .d.e.r.s.AbstractElasticsearchRepository : failed to load elasticsearch nodes : org.elasticsearch.client.transport.NoNodeAvailableException: None of the configured nodes are available: [{#transport#-1}{127.0.0.1}{127.0.0.1:9300}]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To me it seems like the clusternames do not match. Try this parameters:

Properties in YAML Syntax:

```
### elastic properties
spring.data:
  elasticsearch:
    cluster-name: yourclustername
    cluster-nodes: localhost:9300
    repositories.enabled: true
```

youclustername has to match the clustername you gave in the elasticsearch.yml config on paramaeter "cluster.name:".

The cluster-nodes must match the "network.host" from elasticsearch.yml (+ the port which is default 9300)

Next you need to scan for the repositories like this:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableElasticsearchRepositories(basePackages = "elasticsearch")
public class Application {
...
```

Comment: I have put my elasticsearch properties in application.properties. How can I specify my clustername in application.properties?

Comment: Just concat the propertypaths like this: ```spring.data.elasticsearch.cluster-name=yourclustername```

Comment: Your solution is successful and I am able to register index in elasticsearch. But I see no data or mapping on `http://localhost:9200/moviedb/_mappin/movie` I see the following data

    {"moviedb_test":{"mappings":{"movie":{}}}}

Comment: The mappings are created when the first data comes in. So You have to index stuff first. Alternatively you can specify the mappings yourself (@Mapping(mappingPath = "/mappings/movie.json") on document Level)